# Getting data from two tables not working SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get data from two tables based on a condition. Both tables has the same condition just the content change. B contains client data and A contain product data

I am using this this code for stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[printfatura]
    @idfatura int
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM tbl_faturimi b, tblfaturimi_details a
    WHERE b.ID_FATURES = @idfatura 
      AND a.NR_FATURES = @idfatura
```

If I choose the ID =2 then then I should take the result of 3 rows as much as the table has , but instead I am getting 6 row. Data are repeated or duplicate. In tables there is not duplicate or repeated  data, but during the select query process I get repeated data.

What should I change in this code to make it work?

Thanks to everyone

The photos of data :https://www.sendspace.com/file/fk6c1u

Comment: I would suspect one of your tables has multiple rows with the same value, probably your details table.  Sample data would certainly help.  I would also suggest you re-write your select to use proper join syntax, as Donal suggests in his answer.

Comment: NO ONE should be using old-style joins via the where clause. And if your tables have primary keys (which they should), then DISTINCT has no purpose here since your joined rows will naturally be distinct by the inclusion of all columns.

Comment: @Andrew I attached a sendspace link with some pics of table data , where you can see there's no multiple rows with same data

Comment: Don't post data as images, much less links to images.  Put it in a simple table in your post,

Comment: @Eric thank you for your sully advice

Comment: The image you have linked to confuses me. It looks like this is `tbl_faturimi`, but there are duplicate `ID_FATU...` which I take to be `ID_FATURES`? I would have though that the `ID_FATURES` is the primary key for `tbl_faturimi`. Please clarify. (And as has been mentioned: Copy and paste the data as text here. You can use an online tool like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/  to get it readable.)

Comment: "I am trying to get data from two tables based on a condition." - no, you are not. At least this is totally not what your SQL says and unless you considre a join t obe "getting data from 2 tables": WTH are you actually trying do you think that sql does?

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join and group by clause.

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM tbl_faturimi A 
INNER JOIN tblfaturimi_details B 
ON A.FEATURES = B.FEATURES 
GROUP BY A.*, B.*;
```

Hope this helps. :)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[printfatura]
@idfatura int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM tbl_faturimi A
INNER JOIN tblfaturimi_details B
ON A.fk_ID = B.pk_ID
GROUP BY A.SomeColumn
WHERE A.fk_ID = @idfatura
END;
```

Comment: I edited the question. Added a sendspace line where are some pic of the tables data. Sorry that I couldn't insert here cause the no of reputation point. I am new on this forum

Comment: You should insert the image here in this site. Could help you much faster. I am also new in this site and I am still learning queries.

Comment: I cant, cause I must have 10 point to be able to insert images

Comment: Is your Table A.FEATURES  is foreign key to TABLE B.FEATURES?

Comment: If it is. Use the code that I suggested. Hope it works :)

Comment: yes the tables are connected together in a relationship PK, FK with this column ID

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[printfatura]
    @idfatura int
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM tbl_faturimi  inner join  tblfaturimi_details a
    ON b.ID_FATURES=a.NR_FATURES
WHERE b.ID_FATURES = @idfatura 
      AND a.NR_FATURES = @idfatura
```

OR

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[printfatura]
    @idfatura int
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM tbl_faturimi b, tblfaturimi_details a
    WHERE b.ID_FATURES = @idfatura 
      AND a.NR_FATURES = @idfatura
AND b.ID_FATURES=a.NR_FATURES
```

As per the syntax When we try to join two table we have to write a ON clause which contains the matching columns of both tables.

Comment: I've formatted the code for you. For next time: It's easy; just highlight the code and click `{}` in the editor.

Comment: While it is good to recommend proper joins, `b.ID_FATURES=a.NR_FATURES` is always true when `b.ID_FATURES = @idfatura AND a.NR_FATURES = @idfatura`. So, this is not the problem.